# How can I increment query value in python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-update

```
self.mycursor = self.mydb.cursor()
self.sql1 = "UPDATE counter SET count = %s WHERE id = %s"
self.val1 = (str(int('count' + 1)), '1')
self.mycursor.execute(self.sql1, self.val1)
self.mydb.commit()
```

in this part of code I want to increment the query value

Comment: Explain your question little bit more

Comment: What do YOU mean by "increment the query value"?  Your query does not return a value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want increment the counter by 1 for a given id, you can do:

```
self.sql1 = "UPDATE counter SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = %s"
self.val1 = (1)
self.mycursor.execute(self.sql1, self.val1)
```

Comment: It's not clear what `val1` should be, but I assume the OP has the context to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, I assume you want to increment the count value for a given id:

```
        self.mycursor = self.mydb.cursor()
        self.sql1 = "UPDATE counter SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = %s"
        self.mycursor.execute(self.sql1, self.val1)
        self.mydb.commit()
```